# Make AndroidView propagate touch events to underlying Composable

Tags: android, android-view, android-jetpack-compose

Having the following layout, is it possible to make `Button` (or any other views under `AndroidView`) receive touch events even though the `AndroidView` overlays the whole screen? I was able to make it work with two `Composable`s or two old-fashioned `View`s, but not with a `Composable` and a `View`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SomeScreen() {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
        AndroidView(
            viewBlock = {
                View(it).apply {
                    setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what about disabling touch events for the view itself, so any touch event will be handled or intercepted by composable?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Touch events just never got to the underlying composable for some reason.

Comment: Have same issue and no solution, I have tried: object: FrameLayout(context){
                           override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                               return false; // super.onTouchEvent(event)
                           }
                       }.apply{
                            isClickable = false
                            isFocusable  = false
                        }

Nothing helps.

Comment: I also have this problem in reverse. There seems to be no way to intercept touch events in compose, but also allow View underneath to receive them

Comment: Almost 3 years later and I have the same exact problem. Sad that no one answered it...